# run python script on startup - debian

Tags: python, terminal, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have created an application using webcam.  here my application opens a window to display the image. I want to run that application on startup. if i put startup file in rc.local, it runs successfully at startup but not allowing to show window. it shows -

```
gtk warning cannot open display.
```

how to show window? please help me guys!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running LXDE (default on raspbian)

Add a .desktop file to your ~/.config/autostart directory (create one if not available) with 3 lines saying :

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application
Exec=python /path/to/your/application.py arguments
```

UPDATE: updated with Don Question's remark

Comment: thanks for ur rply!! but im using python file. how to init in "Exec"?

Comment: consider `python /path/to/your/application.py arguments`

Comment: thanks don it worked... but I can able to access desktop. I need to run only this application and have to lock desktop and other files! is there any way?